# displaying image from sql server database in php

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to use PDO to display image stored in a sql server database in a varbinary(max) field.

```
$conp = sqlsrv_connect("localhost", array("database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"uid", "PWD"=>"somepassword"));
$id=16;
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conp, "select image from image_tbl where id = $id");
$getAsType = SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY);
if (sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ))
{
$image = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0, $getAsType);
header("Content-type:image/jpeg;");
fpassthru($image)
}
```

the above code displays the image correctly. If I try to use PDO as follows it shows a broken image icon.

```
$sql = "SELECT image FROM image_tbl WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conp->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(&$_GET['id']));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
header("Content-type:image/jpeg;");
echo $image;
```

without the header information it shows the same data. what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: when I put `file_put_contents('test.jpg', $data);` it stores the image correctly. But I still cannot show it on the browser. May be there is something to do with the content-type. Don't know. 
EDIT: I have changed the `print_r($image);` with `echo $image;`.

Comment: are you doing print_r($image) only for debugging?

Comment: yes for debugging only.